# Configuring OpenSSH according to GitLab's documentation

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys, openssh

I've stumbled upon [GitLab's documentation for setting up OpenSSH keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths):

The documentation says to create a file `~/.ssh/config` and gives the following example:

```
# GitLab.com server
Host gitlab.com
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/config/private-key-filename-01

# Private GitLab server
Host gitlab.company.com
RSAAuthentication yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/config/private-key-filename
```

However, I think that the example paths for `IdentityFile` should be `~/.ssh/private-key-filename` and not `~/.ssh/config/private-key-filename`, since `~/.ssh/config` is a file and not a folder.
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config` file path is not related to `IdentityFile` path and you're free to use what you want. But there is surely a typo since it's not really common to place keys in the `~/.ssh/config/` directory. Most people have their keys in `~/.ssh/`. You're right, this example is wrong. You can't have the configuration file `config` along with a `config` directory containing your keys.

Comment: My doubt is that `~/.ssh/config` is already a *file* (the SSH configuration file without any file extension). Thus, at least in my environment (Ubuntu 14.04), I cannot create a *folder* `~/.ssh/config/` to put my private keys into it. In other words: you cannot create both a file and a folder with exactly the same name.

Comment: You're right, I edited the answer. So yes the example is wrong.